# How do I revert back to a former Git commit and then save it in a separate branch?

Tags: git, github

I have over-engineered myself into a corner.  The two things that need to happen are:

1. How do I revert back to an earlier *working* version of my code?...and **simultaneously**,
2. How do I then create a *separate* branch to save that code while still having a saved version of my new code to draw from?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you know the commit SHA you want to go back to:

```
git reset <SHA>
git checkout -b <new_branch_name>
```

Comment: You can add `--soft` flag to be sure:

Answer (score 2):

Before switching branches, if you have pending changes, commit them.

If you know the commit SHA you want to go back to, you can create a new branch from it and switch to it:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> SHA
```

Answer (score 1):

Note down the SHA of the last commit (say e123asd)

To remove last commit from branch 1

`git reset --hard HEAD^`

Switch to branch 2

`git cherry-pick e123asd`

This will bring the last commit to this new branch.